# Qt ColumnLayout full screen

Tags: qt, qml

Qt: 5.11.1
OS: Windows 10 64bit

This is Qt Quick application. when the window is in full screen mode. The layout becomes strange. I think it's an afterimage of the previous size.

startup

[image]

full screen

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

ColumnLayout{
    spacing: 2
    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        color: "red"
        Layout.preferredWidth: 40
        Layout.preferredHeight: 40
    }

    Rectangle {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
        color: "green"
        Layout.preferredWidth: 40
        Layout.preferredHeight: 70
    }

    Rectangle {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        color: "blue"
        Layout.preferredWidth: 70
        Layout.preferredHeight: 40
    }

    Rectangle {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        color: "orange"
        Layout.preferredWidth: 70
        Layout.preferredHeight: 40
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nice, but what is your question?

Comment: Looks pretty much like a bug. You should report it here: https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but a simplification of the problem

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    // Works with any Item
    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "red"
        width: 40
        height: 40
    }

}
```

**How to reproduce**

- On Windows 10, click on the window's maximize button
- Previous frame is not cleared

Could be related to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54451

New bug created https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70570